# Centroids of each grid cell

Tags: r, grids-graticules, centroids

I have a grid created by mean the following script:

```
# My grid [using package 'sf']
worldGrid <- st_make_grid(x = worldMap, what = "polygons", cellsize = 10)
worldGrid <- st_sf(idcell = 1:length(worldGrid), geom = worldGrid) %>% 
st_cast("POLYGON")
```

What I want to obtain is a `SpatialPolygonDataframe` with three columns:
`idcell`, `LONG`, `LAT`

where the coordinates 'LONG' and 'LAT' represent the longitude and latitude of the centroids of each cell of my grid, respectively.

Is that possible in R?

Comment: I would use raster package for this, but try st_centroid(worldGrid) and then st_coordinates() on that to get a matrix. Using sf here is really round-about though, raster(xmn, xmx, ymn, ymn, nrow, ncol) and then coordinates() is far simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid reply. Unfortunately, st_centroid() does not work. The error wich I obtain is: "st_centroid does not give correct centroids for longitude/latitude data"

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning - can you confirm? Just ignore it, my take is that there's no such thing as "correct" for centroid, there are many definitions and different contexts and I think in your case it's obvious and uncontroversial.

Comment: It's just a warning on my system and it provides centroids without any other transforms: `st_centroid(st_make_grid(x = st_as_sf(maps::map("world", fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE)), what = "polygons", cellsize = 10))`

Comment: Both of you are absolutely right: the code "st_centroid(worldGrid) " works, it was just a 'warning'. I obtain the coordinates, but only as matrix and not as SpatialPolygonDataframe.

Comment: You should get the coordinates as an `sfc` object, not a matrix or a SpatialPolygonDataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I get that you want to create a raster that has the extent of the entire world. Here is a way that you can use in order to create the raster and find the centroids of each grid cell.

```
cs = 10.0 # grid cell size 
worldMap <- as( raster::extent(-180, 180, -90, 90), "SpatialPolygons") # Extent of grid to SpatialPolygons
wgs.84 <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
proj4string(worldMap) <- crs(wgs.84) 
class(worldMap)
plot(worldMap)
ras <- raster(worldMap, resolution = cs) # Create raster using the extent 
ras[] <- 1:ncell(r)
cat("\n", "Number of cells in raster: ", ncell(ras), "\n")  
mw <- as(ras, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
class(mw)
plot( as(mw, "SpatialPolygons") )

grid_center <- coordinates(mw) #Determine centroids of grid cells 
centers<- SpatialPoints(grid_ctr, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(e)))
plot(centers,add=T)
```